# writing loaded apache modules to disk before stoping or restarting systemd service

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I want to write list of  loaded apache modules to disk in a file before stoping or restarting systemd service.

So I added in the apache2.service

```
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl -M > /home/ciasto/services/logs/apache2/loaded_mods
```

but this on stop throws error

```
$ sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-25 16:20:37 United; 3min 8s ago
  Process: 7269 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl -M >  /home/ciasto/services/logs/apache2/loaded_mods (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6245 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 25 16:20:36 rockpi apachectl[7269]:   -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Aug 25 16:20:36 rockpi apachectl[7269]:   -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES: show all included configuration files
Aug 25 16:20:36 rockpi apachectl[7269]:   -t                 : run syntax check for config files
Aug 25 16:20:36 rockpi apachectl[7269]:   -T                 : start without DocumentRoot(s) check
Aug 25 16:20:36 rockpi apachectl[7269]:   -X                 : debug mode (only one worker, do not detach)
Aug 25 16:20:36 rockpi apachectl[7269]: Action '-M >  /home/ciasto/services/logs/apache2/loaded_mods' failed.
Aug 25 16:20:36 rockpi apachectl[7269]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 25 16:20:36 rockpi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 25 16:20:37 rockpi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 25 16:20:37 rockpi systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting a usage error.  `apachectl` is responding as if you called it as:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl '-M > /home/ciasto/services/logs/apache2/loaded_mods'
```

You can see that the arguments are: `-M`, `>`, `/home/...`

The `ExecStop=` line is not `sh` and does not support some of the `sh` operators like `&`, `>` or `|`.  If you want to use those operators call a shell directly and pass the command as an argument:

```
ExecStop=+/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/apachectl -M > /home/ciasto/services/logs/apache2/loaded_mods'
```

---

As you noticed in the comments, your service has `User=www-data`.  `www-data` may not have execute permission for things in `sbin`, or write permission for `/home/ciasto/*`.  Therefore you may need to run this command (and only this command) with root permissions while letting the other lines still run as `www-data`.  Using `ExecStop=+/bin/sh` instead of `ExecStop=/bin/sh` will do this for you.

A little demo:

```
User=www-data
ExecStop=/usr/bin/whoami
ExecStop=+/usr/bin/whoami
```

will write the following to the journal:

```
www-data
root
```

Comment: I was getting error becuase apache2ctl on execution reads the default_site-ssl.conf but the apache2ctl from the apache2.service is not running with root user but www-data and group and the ssl pem cert file is not when non root user.

Comment: so  I added a  sudo similar to what you did but in separate shell script

Comment: `sudo` is interactive and so you shouldn't depend on it, especially with system-users. If your service uses `User=` but needs an `ExecStop=` with full privileges, prefix your command with a [`+`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=).  I've edited the `ExecStop=` in my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: apache2.service is supposed to run with user `www-data` and group `www-data` how am I supposed to run the process from `ExecStop`  as  root user then ?

Comment: That's what the `+` does in `ExecStop=+`.  I'll write further explanation in the answer.

Comment: Also some of `ExecStop=` has `-` what does that mean ?

Comment: The [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) says: "If the executable path is prefixed with `-`, an exit code of the command normally considered a failure (i.e. non-zero exit status or abnormal exit due to signal) is recorded, but has no further effect and is considered equivalent to success".  In your case, your service failed because of an exit code. If you had a `-` prefix, your service would have been considered a success, even though it didn't successfully do what you wanted.  I think the failure was useful to discover the problem.